# If $3 \mid (a + b)$ then $3 \mid a$ and $3 \mid b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that:

> If $3 \mid (a + b)$, then $3 \mid a$ and $3 \mid b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are integers)

Is there a direct proof for this? What's the best way to go about proving this? It seems when I assume the contrapositive I get a bunch of cases. Perhaps too many?

Comment: I hope not, because it's obviously false.

Comment: Did you try any examples?  Hint:  look for integers which add to $3$.

Comment: Hahaha. Whoops sorry guys. Feel pretty dumb :P

Comment: $a$ and $-a{}{}{}$

Comment: $a = 4$ and $b = 5$ ?.

Answer (score 4):

$3$ divides $2+1$ but $3$ divides neither $2$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$3|a+b \implies$

$a + b = 3k \implies $

$a = 3k - b$.

Let $k$ be anything you like.  Let $b$ be anything you like.  No reason for $b$ to be divisible by $3$.

It'd be interesting (almost) to instead prove: if $3|a + b$ then $3|a$ if and only if $3|b$.

....or.....

Maybe you were supposed to prove the converse:  If $3|a$ and $3|b$ then $3|a+b$.  Which is pretty simple to prove.

But the implication only goes one way.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that if $3|a$ and $3|b$ then $3|(a+b)$, but the converse is false, for example $a=1,b=2$.